# Why does I'm getting "Service not registered" exception, even though I not used any service in Android - Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, service

I haven't used any receiver or something. But I used Firebase in my Android project. Previously I was not getting this exception, but suddenly it is showing!

**Exception:**

```
W: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzjp@4701ac1
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1751)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1776)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:741)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:55)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.unbindService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:50)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zziv.zzag(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.5.0:245)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zziv.zzal(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.5.0:262)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zziv.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.5.0:336)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zziu.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.5.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzai.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.5.0:7)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfy.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.5.0:21)
```

There is nothing important in **Manifest** file.

**Buld.gradle (app):**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-rc03'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Build.gradle (module)**

```
dependencies {
    ......

//Google Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
 //Google Location
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'

    //Shimmer Layout
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    //Google Auth
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.4.0'
```

**BaseApplication**

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
        FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
    }

    protected void showLog(String msg) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), msg);
    }

}
```

**Troubleshooting:**

0. Found this: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/measurement/package-summary
1. Searched on stackoverflow, but not found proper solution
2. Checked Manifest file
3. While testing, Firebase services are running fine
4. Not understood, what to debug where!

Thank you!

Comment: Did you apply plugin on your gradle files for play services? like so;                                  
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: @samuelowino yes, check in question na, and this is problem with Google Analytics dependencies: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/measurement/package-summary

Comment: If all the firebase services you are using are working properly then probably you should ignore this since its a Warning level log

Comment: @samuelowino no no,  I want to fix this, please! There is some problem with Firebase analytics

Comment: Exactly if it affects your application's requirements then you should look into it, just seems like an internal firebase problem.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the app after adding firebase to your project?

Comment: @samuelowino doing.......

Comment: @samuelowino Same problem!

Comment: @samuelowino project added from last so many months ago!

Comment: @samuelowino without Firebase analytics also same problem

Comment: In your BaseApplication#onCreate call Firebase.initializeApp(context); before the .getInstance calls

Comment: @samuelowino Added, uninstalled and tried, same problem

Comment: @samuelowino sam, any solution?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1662

Comment: Adding:
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.4.0'
seems to solve the issue (the warning is no longer logged).

Comment: Let me know if that solution works for you...

Comment: @samuelowino adding sam

Comment: @samuelowino solved! Please write the answer for the same, and also I'm getting this: " The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." Actually I'm loading image from firebase storage through glide in main activity inside adapter, so I use handler inside a onBindViewHolder, is it a best practice?

Comment: You should have an AsyncTask to load the images and add them to your image view with glide on the postExecute, don't fetch directly via Glide. maybe create a model, link the model to your recycler view adapter, load the list of the models, then pass that list to your adapter which should be linked to your recycler view. https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Comment: @samuelowino Thanks Sam for the suggestion, let me check and come back to you

Comment: @samuelowino Problem, I don't want to load all images together! let user swipe recyclerview and do. So!!

Comment: You can use the publishProgress and onProgressUpdate functions in async task, to allow user to interact with list as it loads

Comment: Look at this : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: @samuelowino I'll check, it may take some time

Comment: @SychiSingh see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1662#issuecomment-744603267

Comment: @Fortran Let's wait then!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**This answer is last updated on:** 12-Feb-2021

**No action is required from our side. Just wait when Google will release this "Fixed" issue in February 2021 approximately.**

> As many of you have pointed out, it turns out that there exist some
> device configurations that trigger the warning even with the
> workaround I provided above.
>
> Unfortunately there is nothing more we can do to "silence" the warning
> on the SDK side. The warning is caused by "Google Play Services"
> itself. The good news is that the root cause of the issue is now
> fixed, however it will roll out to devices around February, so we will
> have to live with this warning for a few months.
>
> I understand that it is causing inconvenience for developers, but fwiw
> it's a warning not a crash. So please bear with us till the update
> gets rolled out. Thanks
>
> PS: Many of you have commented that this warning is sometimes followed
> by a crash(with its own exception), I am fairly confident that in most
> cases, the crash is completely unrelated to this warning and just so
> happens to occur right after it. So please investigate your crashes
> independently, just ignoring the warning. If however you think that
> the crash is related, please provide:
>
> full stack traces at the event of crash relevant dependencies of your
> app ideally steps to reproduce Bumping this reply again, so it's more
> visible for folks.
>
> Once again: The warning is benign and is safe to ignore. The fix will
> get rolled out around Feb 2021, no action is required on developers'
> side, the fix will apply to google play services itself and existing
> apps will stop generating the warning.

Source: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1662#issuecomment-756917362

Comment: I encountered with this problem in Flutter and it is still ongoing.

Comment: Is there no fix so far?

Comment: The issue is still there

Answer (score 35):

Add this to your `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'
}
```

Comment: @samuelowino Could you explain the reasoning behind your answer? How does one deduce which library to include and which version of it?

Comment: Yea would really appreciate if you could explain why we need to add this. thanks in advance

Comment: Why adding this fixes the issue?

Comment: @Rufw91 and OhhhThatVarun it is a known issue in firebase look at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1662

Comment: @samuelowino Sam, I'm getting same prob again!

Comment: Answer is not accurate in todays date

Comment: Safe to ignore / filter out of logs.  The fix is supposed be rolled out around Feb 2021.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1662#issuecomment-756917362

Comment: Answer does not help to remove the error. In my case the correct answer is to upgrade bom to `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0')`.

Comment: @Timo Bähr maybe you should add this as an answer instead of a comment

Comment: @samuel-owino There is more than one question open, here I already posted the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64820697/how-to-fix-exception-thrown-while-unbinding-java-lang-illegalargumentexception/65048232#65048232

Comment: That's great @Timo

Comment: don't know how yet, but it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar issue but with AdMob in the android emulator. Search for a solution but I found nothing.
finally, I close the emulator, open the AVD manager wipe emulator data, reopen the emulator then the warning exception was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Dev's who are facing issue on this problem i have checked a lot with  com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1 i think so some dependencies has to be changed on flutter side so as to support the latest one.

But still you can have your app working without any exception using this :
in your //build.gradle file ...

Just replace the bom version or you can have my own which i am using too..

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
}
```

Comment: This isn't a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. But on checking at firebase console I found firebase error as
"Storage full" it means free space for month is used for database.

[image]

Comment: It's a different thing!

Comment: @SychiSingh This answer might be helpful for someone else.

Comment: Nope. Question's actual answer is related to Android devices play service verion. Once it will rollout, this warning will be gone.

Comment: No You are wrong. This portal is to help people. Sometime some cases get missed. And by checking all the answers person can get hints. Its not good to argue.

Comment: you'll still face the issue after that also because it is not related firebase limit. it is related to Android devices with some of the play services version.