# Flutter and firebase_messaging - Push Notification not working for Android

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Since two weeks I try to setup push notifications for iOS and Android devices with `firebase_messaging 8.0.0-dev.11`. On iOS everything works like a charm. I receive backend and in app notifications as well. But for Android I can't get it to work. I receive neither backend nor in app notifications.

If I try to get a background notification, I get the error:

```
I/flutter ( 9518): FlutterFire Messaging: An error occurred in your background messaging handler:
I/flutter ( 9518): type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'
```

... and the app crashes.

If I try to get an In App Notification the `onMessage.listen` event not fires. But in the console I get a `broadcast received for message` with the json object of my notification.

Also the error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lt@c879c4d`

I'm sending the notification inside a Firebase Cloud function like this:

```
const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
    notification: {
        titleLocKey: "new_entry_title",
        bodyLocKey: "new_entry_desc",
        titleLocArgs: `["${enteredUserName}", "${enteredUserID}", "${guestbookID}", "new_entry_added"]`,
        bodyLocArgs: `["${enteredUserName}"]`,
        badge: "1",
        sound: "default",
    },
}

return fcm.sendToDevice(userToken, payload, {
    priority: "high",
});
```

---

### Additional context

I followed the official migration guide to use the new version of firebase_messaging
(https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration)

---

#### Flutter doctor output

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on macOS 11.0.1 20B29 darwin-x64, locale de-DE)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

---

#### Flutter dependencies

```
Dart SDK 2.10.4
Flutter SDK 1.22.4
virtual_guestbook 1.0.0+8

dependencies:
- cached_network_image 2.3.2+1 [flutter flutter_cache_manager octo_image]
- carousel_slider 2.2.1 [flutter]
- cupertino_icons 0.1.3
- dio 3.0.10 [http_parser path]
- easy_localization 2.3.3 [flutter intl shared_preferences args path flutter_localizations]
- file_picker 2.0.10 [flutter flutter_web_plugins flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_core 0.5.3 [firebase_core_platform_interface flutter quiver meta firebase_core_web]
- firebase_database 4.4.0 [flutter firebase_core]
- firebase_messaging 8.0.0-dev.11 [meta flutter firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_messaging_platform_interface firebase_messaging_web]
- firebase_storage 4.0.1 [flutter firebase_core]
- flutter 0.0.0 [characters collection meta typed_data vector_math sky_engine]
- flutter_colorpicker 0.3.4 [flutter]
- flutter_inapp_purchase 3.0.0 [http meta flutter platform]
- flutter_inner_drawer 0.5.7+2 [flutter]
- flutter_launcher_icons 0.8.1 [image args yaml path]
- flutter_localizations 0.0.0 [flutter intl characters collection meta path typed_data vector_math]
- flutter_secure_storage 3.3.5 [meta flutter]
- font_awesome_flutter 8.10.0 [flutter]
- gallery_saver 2.0.1 [flutter path_provider http path]
- get 3.17.1 [flutter]
- get_storage 1.3.2 [flutter path_provider get]
- image 2.1.18 [archive xml meta]
- image_gallery_saver 1.6.4 [flutter]
- intl 0.16.1 [path]
- lottie 0.5.1 [flutter archive characters charcode collection logging meta path vector_math]
- modal_bottom_sheet 0.2.0+1 [flutter]
- multi_image_picker 4.7.14 [flutter meta]
- painter 0.4.0 [flutter]
- path_provider 1.6.24 [flutter path_provider_platform_interface path_provider_macos path_provider_linux path_provider_windows]
- persistent_bottom_nav_bar 2.1.0 [flutter]
- pin_code_fields 5.0.1 [flutter]
- provider 4.3.2+2 [flutter nested collection]
- pull_to_refresh 1.6.2 [flutter]
- share 0.6.5+2 [meta mime flutter]
- uuid 2.2.2 [crypto convert]
- video_compress 2.1.0 [flutter]
- video_player 0.11.1+2 [meta video_player_platform_interface video_player_web flutter]
- zefyr 0.12.0 [flutter collection url_launcher quill_delta notus meta quiver_hashcode]

dev dependencies:
- flutter_test 0.0.0 [flutter test_api path fake_async clock stack_trace vector_math async boolean_selector characters charcode collection matcher meta source_span stream_channel string_scanner term_glyph typed_data]

transitive dependencies:
- archive 2.0.13 [crypto args path]
- args 1.6.0
- async 2.5.0-nullsafety.1 [collection]
- boolean_selector 2.1.0-nullsafety.1 [source_span string_scanner]
- characters 1.1.0-nullsafety.3
- charcode 1.2.0-nullsafety.1
- clock 1.1.0-nullsafety.1
- collection 1.15.0-nullsafety.3
- convert 2.1.1 [charcode typed_data]
- crypto 2.1.5 [collection convert typed_data]
- fake_async 1.2.0-nullsafety.1 [clock collection]
- ffi 0.1.3
- file 5.2.1 [intl meta path]
- firebase_core_platform_interface 2.1.0 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface quiver]
- firebase_core_web 0.2.1+1 [firebase_core_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins meta js]
- firebase_messaging_platform_interface 1.0.0-dev.7 [flutter meta firebase_core plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_messaging_web 0.1.0-dev.2 [flutter flutter_web_plugins meta firebase_core firebase_core_web firebase_messaging_platform_interface js service_worker]
- flutter_blurhash 0.5.0 [flutter meta]
- flutter_cache_manager 1.4.2 [flutter path_provider uuid http path sqflite pedantic clock file rxdart]
- flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle 1.0.11 [flutter]
- flutter_web_plugins 0.0.0 [flutter characters collection meta typed_data vector_math]
- http 0.12.2 [http_parser path pedantic]
- http_parser 3.1.4 [charcode collection source_span string_scanner typed_data]
- js 0.6.2
- logging 0.11.4
- matcher 0.12.10-nullsafety.1 [stack_trace]
- meta 1.3.0-nullsafety.3
- mime 0.9.7
- nested 0.0.4 [flutter]
- notus 0.1.5 [collection meta quill_delta quiver_hashcode]
- octo_image 0.3.0 [flutter flutter_blurhash]
- path 1.8.0-nullsafety.1
- path_provider_linux 0.0.1+2 [path xdg_directories path_provider_platform_interface flutter]
- path_provider_macos 0.0.4+4 [flutter]
- path_provider_platform_interface 1.0.3 [flutter meta platform plugin_platform_interface]
- path_provider_windows 0.0.4+1 [path_provider_platform_interface meta path flutter ffi win32]
- pedantic 1.9.2 [meta]
- petitparser 3.1.0 [meta]
- platform 2.2.1
- plugin_platform_interface 1.0.3 [meta]
- process 3.0.13 [file intl meta path platform]
- quill_delta 1.1.3 [collection quiver_hashcode]
- quiver 2.1.3 [matcher meta]
- quiver_hashcode 2.0.0
- rxdart 0.24.1
- service_worker 0.2.4 [js]
- shared_preferences 0.5.12+4 [meta flutter shared_preferences_platform_interface shared_preferences_linux shared_preferences_macos shared_preferences_web shared_preferences_windows]
- shared_preferences_linux 0.0.2+4 [file flutter meta path path_provider_linux shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_macos 0.0.1+11 [shared_preferences_platform_interface flutter]
- shared_preferences_platform_interface 1.0.4 [meta flutter]
- shared_preferences_web 0.1.2+7 [shared_preferences_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins meta]
- shared_preferences_windows 0.0.1+3 [shared_preferences_platform_interface flutter ffi file meta path path_provider_platform_interface path_provider_windows]
- sky_engine 0.0.99
- source_span 1.8.0-nullsafety.2 [charcode collection path term_glyph]
- sqflite 1.3.1+1 [flutter sqflite_common path]
- sqflite_common 1.0.2+1 [synchronized path meta]
- stack_trace 1.10.0-nullsafety.1 [path]
- stream_channel 2.1.0-nullsafety.1 [async]
- string_scanner 1.1.0-nullsafety.1 [charcode source_span]
- synchronized 2.2.0+2
- term_glyph 1.2.0-nullsafety.1
- test_api 0.2.19-nullsafety.2 [async boolean_selector collection meta path source_span stack_trace stream_channel string_scanner term_glyph matcher]
- typed_data 1.3.0-nullsafety.3 [collection]
- url_launcher 5.7.2 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface url_launcher_web url_launcher_linux url_launcher_macos url_launcher_windows]
- url_launcher_linux 0.0.1+1 [flutter]
- url_launcher_macos 0.0.1+8 [flutter]
- url_launcher_platform_interface 1.0.8 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_web 0.1.4+1 [url_launcher_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins meta]
- url_launcher_windows 0.0.1+1 [flutter]
- vector_math 2.1.0-nullsafety.3
- video_player_platform_interface 2.2.0 [flutter meta]
- video_player_web 0.1.4 [flutter flutter_web_plugins meta video_player_platform_interface]
- win32 1.7.3 [ffi]
- xdg_directories 0.1.2 [meta path process]
- xml 4.5.1 [collection convert meta petitparser]
- yaml 2.2.1 [charcode collection string_scanner source_span]
```

---

Where is the issue here?

Comment: Check here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4052#issuecomment-724748014

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Exception thrown while unbinding, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lp@9f7d4ca" exception in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64820697/how-to-fix-exception-thrown-while-unbinding-java-lang-illegalargumentexception)

Comment: Tried this already. This not fixes the issue :( thanks anyway :)

Comment: I guess you've resolved this per this [GitHub post](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4387). Could you confirm if this is the solution? Also, it would be nice if you can share the solution here and mark as answer.