# Do I need a service to open camera on device?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

Android app runs fine when using an emulator - opens camera and uploads image no foreground service being used, but when I test on device I am thrown this error:

```
W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lu@b3804ca
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1766)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1810)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:741)
        at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516081@20.45.16 (120400-0):1)
        at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516081@20.45.16 (120400-0):2)
        at lv.E(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516081@20.45.16 (120400-0):9)
        at lf.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516081@20.45.16 (120400-0):3)
        at ef.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516081@20.45.16 (120400-0):3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at iy.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516081@20.45.16 (120400-0):5)
```

Could someone explain this to me and then point me in the right direction regarding services I have read the documentation and understand I may need to declare FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_CAMERA but I am unsure about creating a new MyService class and how that interacts with the manifest file

Manifest file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       package="com.example.sailing_tracker">
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />


       <application
           android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
           android:supportsRtl="true"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
           tools:targetApi="m">
           <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
           <activity android:name=".DashboardActivity" />
           <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
           <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>
          <service android:name=".ForegroundCameraService"/>
       </application>
   </manifest>
```

Service

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;


public class ForegroundCameraService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have not register your service in manifest file.Register it in Manifest.

Comment: Check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64820697/how-to-fix-exception-thrown-while-unbinding-java-lang-illegalargumentexception I dont know you are using firebase or not but this issue is same as your one.